# Algorithm for finding a rectangle constrained to its parent

Tags: c++, clipping

Basically what I want to do is illustrated here:
[image]

I  start with A and B, then B is conformed to A to create C.

The idea is, given TLBR rectangles A, B, make C

I also need to know if it produces an empty rectangle (B outside of A case).

I tried this but it just isn't doing what I want:

```
if(clipRect.getLeft() > rect.getLeft())
    L = clipRect.getLeft();
else
    L = rect.getLeft();

if(clipRect.getRight() < rect.getRight())
    R = clipRect.getRight();
else
    R = rect.getRight();

if(clipRect.getBottom() > rect.getBottom())
    B = clipRect.getBottom();
else
    B = rect.getBottom();

if(clipRect.getTop() < rect.getTop())
    T = clipRect.getTop();
else
    T = rect.getTop();

if(L < R && B < T)
{
    clipRect = AguiRectangle(0,0,0,0);
}
else
{
    clipRect = AguiRectangle::fromTLBR(T,L,B,R);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: After Ran's correction, it looks right. Can you give an example of its failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a mistake in the final condition checking whether or not the intersection rectangle is empty.

You check `L < R && B < T`, but it seems like the condition for an empty rectangle should be:

`L > R || B < T`.

By the way, you can make your code a little simpler and easier to read by using `Min` and `Max` functions. You have a lot of this pattern:

```
if (x < y)
    a = x;
else
    a = y;
```

Which can be written simply as

```
a = Min(x, y);
```

**Edit**

Another mistake is that you take the maximum bottom and the minimum top. You should be taking the minimum bottom and the maximum top. (Assuming the rectangles correspond to screen coordinates, where the top actuallly has lower *y* values.

Comment: Still doesn't do what I'm hoping for, maybe the algorithm's wrong?

Comment: Are my > and <'s okay to you?

Answer (score 1):

Logically, these are two different problems.  I would first write an *is_intersected()* function returning an appropriate boolean value.

If the rects do intersect, I would then perform a clip operation that resembled the following pseudocode:

```
C.left.x = max(A.left.x, B.left.x);
C.right.x = min(A.right.x, B.right.x);

C.left.y = max(A.left.y, B.left.y);
C.right.y = min(A.right.y, B.right.y);
```